# Goto not working in batch file, skips user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working on a program to backup Fallout 4 Saves, because using console commands can bork a save file this time around. Unfortuanly, while all of the parts are working independently, the little menu I have made isn't working!

For some reason the if %1m% == _ goto _ commands are doing nothing, and the program skips back to the label 1, a feature I put there in case of invalid input.

What's wrong here?

```
@echo off
title Fallout 4 Save Backup Utility
color 0a

:1
cls
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\FalloutBackup\data\"
set /a count=0
for /d /r %%i in (*.*) do set /a count+=1
popd
echo %count% Backup(s^) currently exist.
echo.
echo.
set /a value=0
set /a sum=0
FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO (
set /a value=%%~zI/1000000
set /a sum=!sum!+!value!
)
@echo Backups files using about: !sum! Mb
endlocal
echo.
echo.
echo Delete all but last backup? y/n?
set /p 1m=
if %1m% == y goto 3
if %1m% == Y goto 3
if %1m% == n goto 2
if %1m% == N goto 2
cls
goto 1
```

Comment: Change your variable 1m to m1.  CMD interpreter is not smart enough to know that you are trying to reference an environmental variable and not a argument passed to the batch file.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you! I have NO IDEA why that worked, but it did!

Comment: batch interprets %1 as a parameter given to the batch-file when starting it. Therefore you should never start variable names in batch with numbers

Answer (score 1):

As Squash man Said:
Change your variable 1m to m1. CMD interpreter is not smart enough to know that you are trying to reference an environmental variable and not a argument passed to the batch file. –

I also recommend using quotes for the "%m1%"=="y". Also, the /I parameter after IF makes the answer not cap-sensitive, a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use CHOICE and ERRORLEVEL for option selection. The relevant code changes would be:

```
echo.
choice /c yn /m "Delete all but last backup? "
IF ERRORLEVEL 255 goto end
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto donotdelete
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto dodelete
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto end
goto begin
```

(255 and 0 are there for escapes.)
(You will need to obtain the choice COM file, which is readily available.)